# How can I include a resource for debugging but not deploying?

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

Is it possible for Gradle to use resources for debugging that aren't used for deploying?

My `*.properties` files are generated on the server from `*.config` files and aren't supposed to be included in the jar when it is created with Gradle.

However, I need the `*.properties` files on the classpath when debugging locally with IDEA.

If I copy a properties file from the server and put it in `src/main/resources` the application will run and I can debug it properly from IDEA. However, if I *commit* the file to that directory it will get added to the jar by Gradle on the build server and then deploy it which is not what I want.

To avoid the files from being accidentally deployed, I committed the property files to `src/env-properties` (and periodically manually sync then with the server files). I can then go into the IDEA Project Structure, add a content root and mark the directory as a resource allowing me to debug.

As soon as I refresh the Gradle project from IDEA though, this config is lost.

How do I configure Gradle so that IDEA uses `src/env-properties` as a resource but Gradle doesn't use it for the `jar` task and accidentally deploy it?

**NB:** A few people in the team use eclipse so I'd like `gradlew eclipse` to also add it to the eclipse classpath as well if possible.

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right track with the separate resource folder, you can configure gradle to do exactly what you want:

Create a separate directory for the resources that should only be included when debugging, such as src/debug/resources.

Add the following to your build.gradle file:

```
sourceSets {
  main {
    debug {
      resources {
        srcDir 'src/debug/resources'
      }
    }
  }
}

jar {
  exclude '**/debug/**'
}
```

Rename `resources` to whatever you need, properties or env-properties.

That should do it for you, I can't speak to the Eclipse part of your question, I am blessed with an Eclipse free working environment!

This SO post has useful fancy pants stuff for complicated builds: [How to exclude resources from the JAR in Gradle and also run via IntelliJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59401271/how-to-exclude-resources-from-the-jar-in-gradle-and-also-run-via-intellij)